# TestNG automatically disable tests

Tags: unit-testing, testng

I am currently working on getting the Flexmojos project to build with the new Adobe Flex 4.8. The problem is, that with 4.8 one feature is no longer available. If I run the unittests against this sdk, the build will fail. I could disable the failling tests alltogether, but I would like to keep them in place, as they test important features of older Flex SDKs.

Is there a way to automatically have tests skipped if a precondition is not met? I was thinking of some method being called to decide if a test should be executed. Alternatively I could set an environment variable. If there is any other option I would be glad to hear.

Chris

Answer (score 3):

One way i can think of doing this in testNg is by using IAnnotationTransformer listener. Basically you can manipulate the annotation in runtime. here is an example:

Listener:

```
public class SampleAnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation iTestAnnotation, Class aClass, Constructor constructor, Method method) {

    if(method != null){
        if(!isThisTestCompatible(method)){
            //diable the test case.
            iTestAnnotation.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

}

private boolean isThisTestCompatible(Method method){
    //your logic goes here...
    return false;
}
}
```

configure above listener in testNG as shown below:

```
<suite name="Suit" verbose="1">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="SampleAnnotationTransformer" />
</listeners>

//test cases...
```

Worth checking other listeners as well at http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners

Comment: Hey ... this sounds great ... think I'll dig into this :-) Thanks for the pointer :-)

Comment: That's what I was about to recommend as well.